# Где указать лицензию MIT для браузерной игры?

Tags: разработка-игр, лицензирование

Суть лицензии в том что просто нужно вставить письмо.

В игре есть пользовательское соглашение и политика конфиденциальности. Также нажав на правую кнопку перейти в папку source , можно посмотреть код игры, там можно указать этот текст в текстовом файле.

А какое наказание может быть если эту лицензию не соблюсти?

Comment: В "Об игре" каком-нибудь

Comment: можно по подробнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разместите ссылку рядом со ссылками на пользовательское соглашение, и прям так и назовите "Лицензия MIT".

> А какое наказание может быть если эту лицензию не соблюсти?

Такое же как и за любую другую: запрет на использование и компенсация судебных издержек правообладателя. Возмещение убытка в данном случае не грозит, т.к. код и так предоставляется бесплатно.

Comment: Хорошо,я спрашивал у создателя сайта он разрешил указать лицензию в исходном коде игры https://codepen.io/ вот отсюда хочу взять код.